# Cannot connect to nodejs server from client

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sql-server, cors

I was in need for some help regarding my nodeJS server.
I have my Windows Server which is running my frontend and server. My server is in nodeJs and it has all the api i made. This is the index.js of my server.

```
app.use(
    cors({
    origin: "https://localhost:8080",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowedHeaders: [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "content-type",
    "Cookies",
    "cookies",
    "Authorization",
    ],
    })
);
```

The thing is that I can access my API for userlisting by http://158.53.70.6:5000/users from my server itself in chrome and it works. But now i want to actually access it from another PC. How can I do this. Also a side note the frontend is hosted on open internet on https://172.23.50.5:5553/. The frontend on my PC is working but I can't access the data in it that is it cant access the API. Also just a side note if it is important, the db is hosted in MySQL phpmyadmin using Apache on port 80 and 443 and MySQL on port 3306.

This is the error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:5000/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘localhost:3000’).

Comment: So what's the error you get? The CORS setup in the question only allows requests from web apps running at `https://localhost:8080`. You'd need to add more origins if you need to access the service from elsewhere.

Comment: This is the error
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3000’).